# timezone issue with Date.Parse()

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code in my script:

```
Date.parse('10/01/2010 01:01:01')
```

The result I get after running the script is this:

```
September 30, 2010 22:01:01
```

Is it maybe a problem with Date.Parse() or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The date is _formatted_ in your local time zone when you output it. If you don’t like that, output it another way (you did not show what way you are using).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a problem: it's a [**feature**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> The parse method takes a date string (such as "Dec 25, 1995") and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. The local time zone is used to interpret arguments that do not contain time zone information. [...] If you do not specify a time zone, the local time zone is assumed.

... so there's a difference between:

```
Date.parse("Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00");

// ... returns 14400000 in timezone GMT-0400, and other values in other 
// timezones, since there is no time zone specifier in the argument.
```

... and...

```
Date.parse("Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT-0400");
// ... returns 14400000 no matter the local time zone.
```